# $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b),$ and the set $\{x\in(a,b):f'(x)<0\}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b),$ and  assume that the set $\{x\in(a,b):f'(x)<0\}$ is countable then we must have

```
A.f is an increasing function.

B.f is decreasing  function.

C.f is neither increasing nor decreasing function.

D. Can't say anything.
```

How to solve this problem as derivative  has both sign positive as well as negative? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? Given that the set in question is countable, what is the cardinality of the complement (which is...)?

Comment: $f$ has positive derivative on uncountable set

Comment: My intuition would be that the countable set is actually empty since if it's decreasing at a point, then it must be decreasing in an uncountable neighborhood of that point.

Comment: But how to prove mathematically?

Comment: Here the countability for this set seems strange... When a derivative is discontinuous at some point it is [an essential discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity) (not a jump), so if we have some $f'(x)<0$ then it must exists an uncountable number of points in it neighborhood. So, as Alexis said, the set must be empty.

Comment: The derivative of a function needn't be continuous!

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes give the exact answer...thanks lot..

Comment: @SangchulLee: You should write an answer. As motivation, if you don't, I will :-).

Comment: @copper.hat, Thank you, I migrated the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(migrated from the comment)*

As pointed out by other users, the set $\{ x \in (a, b) : f'(x) < 0 \}$ is necessarily empty.

One explanation uses the fact that the derivative of a differentiable function satisfies intermediate value property regardless of its continuity (This is called the [*Darboux theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).):

Assume that we have $x_0 \in (a, b)$ with $f'(x_0) < 0$. Since we know as well that $f'(x_1) \geq 0$ for some $x_1 \in (a, b)$, the intermediate value property tells us that for each $y$ between $f'(x_0)$ and $f'(x_1)$, there is $c$ between $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $f'(c) = y$. In particular, there should exist uncountably many points on $(a, b)$ at which $f'(x) < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that that $f'(x)=0$ in which it is neither increasing nor decreasing.  It could be $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in which case it is increasing.

So as it could be increasing and it could be doing neither it can not be determined.

Which is a very wimpy answer.  But legitimate.

Comment: if $f'=0$ then $f$ is constant and constant function is both increasing and decreasing...

Comment: Oh, it is?  Then never mind.